# How To Use An Expression Tree Type

Tags: c#, lambda

The MSDN documentation on [Lamba Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) provides an example of how to create an expression tree type but it does not show how to use it:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<del> myET = x => x * x;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you complete this console application code so that it actually demonstrates the concept?

Comment: You can compile your expression tree, for sample: `del f = myET.Compile(); int j = f(5);`.

Comment: for reference, `del` is defined earlier in the article to be `delegate int del(int i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Expression Trees contain two parts. A set of parameters and a body. There is only one parameter shown in your example, which is `x` and the body uses that parameter by multiplying it by itself.

Essentially the behavior setup is something like this:

```
public int myET(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

However, in order to access that behavior the value of the Expression must be accessed. This value is a delegate, and is accessed through compiling the expression using [`.Compile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx). Its type will be a `Func` with the type parameters of your `del` delegate which were returning `int` and accepting `int`.

```
delegate int del(int i);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<del> myET = x => x * x;
    del myFunc = myET.Compile();
}
```

Once compiled, the function may be called just like the method shown above with the behavior, where a value for the parameter is sent in, and the result of the code in the body is returned.

```
delegate int del(int i);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<del> myET = x => x * x;
    del myFunc = myET.Compile();
    int fiveSquared = myFunc(5);
    Console.WriteLine(fiveSquared);//25
}
```

Comment: If all you're going to do is compile the expression you'd have been way better off just compiling the lambda as a delegate in the first place.

Comment: @Servy - Just trying to show it step by step since it was part of a basic example.

Comment: Thanks! But I did have to change your code slightly since the type could not be converted to a System.Function
`del myDelegate = myET.Compile();
 int j = myDelegate(5);
`